# subject-verb agreement when "OR" is used in the subject

Tags: subject-verb-agreement

I wrote:

> For example, **the subject or the object** of the sentence **are** directly dependent on the verb and in turn **they** may take other dependents.

Is it "are" or "is"? Or "they" or "it"? Because I used "or" in the subject, I don't know the verb is plural or singular.

Comment: Which is|are your preferred pet, a dog or a cat?  BTW, "they may **take** other dependents".

Comment: *\*Which are your preferred pet, a dog or a cat?* is ungrammatical.

Comment: @snailboat: I agree.  It was socratic.

Answer (score 6):

The conjunction "***or***" is exclusive, which means that if it connects elements (called alternatives) that are *both* in singular, the phrase is considered to have singular number, which means you need to use "***is***" in a sentence like

> The subject *or* the object of the sentence ***is*** directly dependent...

If one of the alternatives is in plural, it depends on the relative order of the alternatives in the sentence.  Choose the number of the closest to the verb alternative:

> The teacher *or* the pupils ***are*** liable for the noise in the classroom.
>   The pupils *or* the teacher ***is*** liable for that racket we keep hearing.

Same goes with other constructs that can stand for both numbers, like "*which*" or "*who*":

> Is it Paul *or* his kids who ***like*** hiking?
>   Was it Paul's kids *or* Paul himself who ***is*** coming to live with us?

Other examples and more on subject-verb agreement can be seen, for instance [here](http://www.wilbers.com/subjectverbagreement.htm).

---

The same agreement needs to exist between the alternatives and any pronoun in a dependent clause.  For instance,

> Has your dog *or* cat had ***its*** vaccinations?

Your sentence therefore needs to be

> For example, the subject *or* the object of the sentence ***is*** directly dependent on the verb and in turn ***it*** may take other dependents.

Comment: What about "they"? could I still use "they" to mean both have the same property.

Comment: Sorry, missed that one.  Going to edit it in.

Comment: @VictorBazarov Does your answer hold for the other coordinator **and** ? (I wanted to ask his question couple of months ago, but I forgot to ask)

Comment: Not sure what you mean.  "And" introduces plural.  How can that "hold"?

Comment: @Cardinal *And* and *or* don't work the same way.